# Import the Smart TV SDK Emulator .OVA image file taking so long

Tags: samsung-smart-tv

Why, when i import .ova image taking so long? any suggest?

Note:
- i use smart tv sdk 5.1
- 2014_Smart_TV_Emulator_5_1.ova
- Virtual Box 4.2.16

I install the requirement like in samsung from written http://samsungdforum.com/Devtools/SdkDownload

Best regard

Answer (score 0):

This problem occurs when you have limited RAM, please consider your RAM Size